# Why do I get this IOException, when I'm not even trying to open the file?

Tags: c#, exception, system.io.directory, getdirectories

I tried this code:

```
var HighestFolder = Directory.GetDirectories("U:/New/Items", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                             .Select(x => x.Replace('\\','/'))
                             .Where(x => x.Split('/').Length >= 5)
                             .OrderByDescending(x => long.Parse(x.Split('/').Last()))
                             .FirstOrDefault();
```

I expected this to return the sub directory with the highest number. But instead, it throws this exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: The system cannot open the file: 'U:\New\Items\0\7917'
```

The folder is clearly valid and accessible and the app created it just moments earlier, and nothing I am seeing should be opening it at all. Why do I get an `IOException`?

**Work around:**
I tried the following code which works successfully for my purposes, but doesnt explain why the previous one is failing.

```
var HighestFolder = Directory.GetDirectories(path)
                    .SelectMany(x => Directory.GetDirectories(x))
                    .Select(x => x.Replace('\\', '/'))
                    .Where(x =>x.Substring(path.Length).Split('/').Length>= 3)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => long.Parse(x.Split('/').Last()));
```

Comment: The GetDirectories will give an expression if ANY file in the folders the user does not have permission to read FILES or FOLDERS.  VS doesn't automatically run with As Admin unless you start VS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.  If running code outside VS you do have As Admin.  If there are files that you do not have permission to read you have to use a recursive algorithm and add a try/catch to continue when you do not have permission.  Have sample code that I can post.  You may have link to other folder that may be causing issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO! A hint from an experienced user: People are more likely to help you if you take the time to provide a [mcve]. Your code, for example, is not minimal, since a lot of those linq steps between `GetDirectories` and `FirstOrDefault` can be removed or simplified, while still reproducing the original problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. I [edit]ed the question to show how to ask a question clearly and directly - your version was good, but it had a bit much distracting formatting, and the screenshot is [not helpful](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). To provide more context on the error, instead use the IDE's options to show you a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, and copy and paste that. Generally it's better to format errors as multi-line code, not as a block quote.

Comment: Shouldn't `"U:New/Items"` be `@"U:New\Items"`?

Comment: @JohnWu I think `@"U:\New\Items"` (note the missing backslash after the drive letter)

Comment: its not the link, it used to get from a variable based on platform, my minimal example, i just strong typed it and missed.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i felt the screenshot showed theres at least read access to the folder and that it was getting the right path before i mistyped it. that is the only information the IDE  gives me, as it also showed in the screenshot

Comment: @jdweng all my permissions seem fine, i can create and delete files in explorer fine, and the app itself created them just minutes before

Comment: May be a file didn't get closed.

Comment: the pc got reboot and the problem persisted. i was able to get around it by changing '.GetDirectories("U:/New/Items", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)' to ;Directory.GetDirectories(path).SelectMany(x => Directory.GetDirectories(x))' which doesnt seem like the right solution. far as i can tell, GetDirectories with AllDIrectories seems broken